# 14.04 LTS on Toshiba Satellite C75D-B. Brightness, WiFi, Fn-keys control and Suspend problems

Tags: laptop, suspend, brightness, toshiba

This is a new laptop that I just bought. Came with Windows 8.1, now is a dual-boot. 
Sound Controls and Mute work with <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd> like they do in Windows, but <kbd>F12</kbd> for WiFi, <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> for brightness do not work. <kbd>F5</kbd> brings up Display control, and <kbd>F2</kbd> brings-up the Power Manager instead of taking Brightness Lower. <kbd>F3</kbd> does nothing.

I also have Brightness control added to the panel, moving mouse up and down does not change screen brightness.

It also does not recover from Suspend.
Am I missing a Toshiba-specific configuration? Synaptic package manager shows `toshset` and `acpi-support` packages installed from  the distribution.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290  solved the Problem with Suspend.

Comment: For wireless issue see [My wireless has suddenly became disabled by hardware switch, BIOS, rfkill, fn+f8 do nothing](//askubuntu.com/q/106568)

Answer (score 1):

This kernel patch is needed to fix acpi keys on C75D-B

```
*** drivers/platform/x86/toshiba_acpi.c 2015-02-08 20:54:22.000000000 -0600
--- drivers/platform/x86/toshiba_acpi.c.fixed   2016-01-2013:32:56.623965574 -0600
*************** static const struct dmi_system_id toshib
*** 247,252 ****
--- 247,258 ----
        DMI_MATCH(DMI_PRODUCT_NAME, "TECRA A50-A"),
    },
},
+   {
+       .matches = {
+           DMI_MATCH(DMI_SYS_VENDOR, "TOSHIBA"),
+           DMI_MATCH(DMI_PRODUCT_NAME, "Satellite C75D-B"),
+       }
+   },
{}
};
```

I have tested this on my Satellite C75D-B7360 and it works! If you are familiar with kernel building this should be a simple matter to patch the file and rebuild toshiba_acpi.ko.