# Can't turn on wifi on Toshiba Satellite C75D

Tags: wireless, function-keys

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my new Toshiba Satellite C75D a number of months ago, and everything worked great for months. Then suddenly, I didn't have wifi access anymore.  I can connect by wire.

`rfkill list` says that my wireless LAN is both hard and soft blocked.

When I try to toggle the switch on the Network Manager to "on" for wifi, it won't let me.

My "hard switch" is the <kbd>F12</kbd> key, but it doesn't seem to to anything.

Someone else had a similar question that didn't seem to get answered, except for the problem they had with suspend: [14.04 LTS on Toshiba Satellite C75D-B. Brightness, WiFi, Fn-keys control and Suspend problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586824/14-04-lts-on-toshiba-satellite-c75d-b-brightness-wifi-fn-keys-control-and-sus).

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:8631]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

It is not a dual boot system.  I set it up to be Ubuntu only.

Comment: Is this a Dualboot system?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Thank you.  I added the output.  And no, it is not Dualboot.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed!  I followed the advice found here: [My wireless has suddenly became disabled by hardware switch, BIOS, rfkill, fn+f8 do nothing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106568/my-wireless-has-suddenly-became-disabled-by-hardware-switch-bios-rfkill-fnf8)

1. Unplug and remove battery
2. Press power button at least 30 seconds
3. Boot up and enter BIOS settings
4. Set to defaults
   I connected to wireless right away!  Happy day!

Comment: Solved my no-wifi issue today, thank you.